# How can I group two ContentControl elements in different table rows?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word form that I've organized in a table. Now I want to group two (and more) checkboxes that aren't in the same table cell - but in different table rows.

How can I select them in a way that I can group them?

I've already tried two different approaches that didn't solve my problem:

1. Select according table cells and group the two checkboxes.
2. Change from text cursor selector to object selector ([image: cursor]).

Comment: Btw, I wasn't sure if this is relevant for superuser or for the regular StackOverflow. Please notify if this is the wrong place. Thanks

Comment: I *think* you have to select the complete block of rows (i.e. the row that contains the first Content Control and all the rows up to and including the row that contains the last Content Control. Otherwise, I do not think Word lets you Group the controls.